# How to open an iPhone app from terminal or using any monkeytalk command?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode5, monkeytalk

Before execution of a Monkeytalk script, I am manually opening my iPhone app on the actual device. I want to launch and close my app using xcode command / Monkeytalk-pro command itself.

Is this possible?

Comment: One of my test cases is "Verify that the app opens and presents a login screen" - It would be great if Monkeytalk could do this but I have a feeling that the agent is only active when the app is running.

Answer (score -1):

MonkeyTalk works by hooking into your application. Since MonkeyTalk never actually overrides anything the operating system does, it can't do anything your app can't do. Which includes the app launching by itself, I'm afraid. That's life with Apple though, we'll never have anything as easy as those Android developers have.